# c# MVC Controller jsonresult action not found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple web page with a a simple purpose: for people to contact someone else. 
To do so, i have created a contract form like this:

```
<form id="mailForm" action="Contact/SendEmailAsync" method="post">

   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailSubject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EMailBody, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @cols = "30", @rows = "7" })
   </div>
<div class="form-group">
<id="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Verstuur bericht" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5">
</div>
</form>
```

I have also tried the razor shorthand version of action.

the submit button is linked to an ajax call as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mailForm = $('mailForm')
        debugger;
        var data = mailForm.serialize()

        //get button by ID
        $('#formSubmit').submit(function () {
            debugger;
            //call a function with parameters
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SendEmailAsync", "Contact")',
                type: 'POST',
                timeout: '12000',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: data,

            })
                .done(function () {
            console.log('done')});
    });
    });

</script>
```

Controller looks like this, but I never hit the breakpoint

```
namespace site.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<JsonResult> SendEmailAsync(Mail mail)
        {
            {
                var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                var message = new MailMessage();
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxx"));  // replace with valid value 
                message.From = new MailAddress("xxxxx");  // replace with valid value
                message.Subject = "site contactformulier";
                message.Body = string.Format(body, mail.FromName, mail.FromEmail, mail.EMailBody); ;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = "xxxx",  // replace with valid value
                    Password = "xxxxx"  // replace with valid value
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.xxxx.be";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                return Json("ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error that i get is that my page is never found:

No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44376/Contact/SendEmailAsync

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don’t need to use JavaScript to submit the form, you’ve already set the route in the form tag, clicking the submit button will just post to your controller method.  If you want to use AJAX you could replace the form tag with Ajax.BeginForm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please remove lines

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

And try again, I believe those are for API Controllers and may not work for MVC Controllers.